# How disable and enable Button Click event depending on some variable in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have one Delphi 10.0 Seattle project to FTP some files to a server.

I will do the following:

1. On Button1 OnClick event, I will calculate something and will make one text file. Edit1 will hold the file name.
2. On Button2 OnClick event, the last 4 characters of the file name will be deleted. The file will be renamed with the new name. Edit2 will hold the new name and it will be uploaded to one server.
3. During the file uploading, no button click will work and the Form cannot be closed. I have used one Boolean variable `FileToBeTranferred`. It is `false` at Form creation.

I have written the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
var
  FileToBeTranferred: boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FileToBeTranferred = false then
    begin
      //Do some calculation
      //Edit1.Text := Output File Name
      FileToBeTranferred := true;
    end
  else
    begin
      Button1.Click(nil);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FileToBeTranferred = true then
  begin
    Edit2.Text := delete(Edit1.Text, (length(Edit1.Text)-4), 4);
    //Upload to Server
    Button2.Click(self);
  end
  else
  begin
    //Upload finished
    FileToBeTranferred := false;
    Button2.Click(nil);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
 if FileToBeTranferred = true then CanClose := false
 else CanClose := true;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileToBeTranferred := false;
end;

end.
```

I am unable to do anything. I am getting too many errors. The errors are as follows:

1. `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter` in `Edit2.Text := delete(Edit1.Text, (length(Edit1.Text)-4), 4);` - for deleting last 4 characters for file rename.
2. `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2034 Too many actual parameters` in `Button2.Click(nil);` - as FTP is in progress so no more modification to the file is allowed. `Button1.Click` will not perform anything.
3. `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2034 Too many actual parameters` in `Button2.Click(self);`- as FTP progress completed so the file is ready to be appended. `Button2.Click` will not perform its usual work.

**What is the solution to this?**

Comment: All sorts of issues here. Firstly, don't assume file extensions are three characters long. Don't assume that files even have extensions. Use a proper function to remove the file extension. You can't use Delete on a property. It needs a variable. Which is what the error message says. Too many parameters means, er, too many parameters. It's really important to read error messages, and not just assume that they carry no information. Don't use a global variable for information relating to the state of the form instance. That's what instance variables are for.

Comment: Don't use default component names. What information is conveyed by Button1 and Button2. Don't test = true or = false. Do `if someBool then` or `if not someBool then` respectively. Make sure you know what version of Delphi you are using. There is no such thing as XE10. Read the version from the caption bar of the IDE. Calling Button2,Click from the Button2 click event handler is bound to lead to an unterminated recursion.

Comment: I have no option. I have to remove last 4 characters of my file name. I have also tried using a variable as   `procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyText : string;
  TextLength : integer;
  NewText : string;
begin
  MyText := Edit1.Text;
  TextLength := length(MyText);
  NewText := delete(MyText, (TextLength-4),4);
  Edit2.Text := NewText;
  if FileToBeTranferred = true then
end;`  For removing last 4 characters of file name. It is also not working.

Comment: Version is RAD Studio XE10 Seattle.

Comment: OK, this is a total waste of our time. That's not the version. There is no such thing as XE10 Seattle. Read the IDE caption bar. What does it say? Does it say "XE10 Seattle"? No, it does not. As for the last 4 characters of the file name, did you read my comment at all? It looks to me as though you have given up trying to understand this and just want somebody else to do it for you. Looking ahead, how will that help you? What will you learn? Read my comments again, and try a little harder.

Comment: I have read your comment again. It is not clear to me. I don't know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170556/discussion-between-hp-owner-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: "You can't use Delete on a property. It needs a variable. Which is what the error message says."

Comment: "I have no option" Yes, you do. You have tons of options. You just need to read what people are telling you more carefully and try to understand them.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have shown is just all kinds of wrong.  Not just the syntax errors, but also logic errors.  Even if the code compiled, your `Button1` click handler will get stuck in an endless recursive loop if `FileToBeTranferred` is true, and your `Button2` click handler will get stuck in an endless recursive loop regardless of `FileToBeTranferred`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FileToBeTranferred: boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not FileToBeTranferred then
  begin
    //Do some calculation
    //Edit1.Text := Output File Name
    FileToBeTranferred := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FileToBeTranferred then
  begin
    Edit2.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Edit1.GetTextLen-4);
    //Upload to Server, wait for completion
    FileToBeTranferred := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := not FileToBeTranferred;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileToBeTranferred := False;
end;

end.
```

That being said, you might consider a different approach.  For instance, one that doesn't require the `FileToBeTranferred` Boolean at all:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  //Do some calculation
  //Edit1.Text := Output File Name
  Button2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button2.Enabled := False;
  Edit2.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Edit1.GetTextLen-4);
  //Upload to Server
  Button1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := Button1.Enabled;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  Button2.Enabled := False;
end;

end.
```

Or, you could combine the two approaches, by enabling/disabling the `TButton` objects based on the current value of `FileToBeTranferred` at any given moment.

You can override the Form's virtual `UpdateActions()` method:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure UpdateActions; override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FileToBeTranferred: boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Do some calculation
  //Edit1.Text := Output File Name
  FileToBeTranferred := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Edit1.GetTextLen-4);
  //Upload to Server, wait for completion
  FileToBeTranferred := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := not FileToBeTranferred;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileToBeTranferred := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateActions;
begin
  inherited;
  Button1.Enabled := not FileToBeTranferred;
  Button2.Enabled := FileToBeTranferred;
end;

end.
```

Or, you can drop a `TActionList` on the Form and assign a `TAction` to each `TButton`, and then enable/disable the `TAction` objects in their `OnUpdate` events:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math, Vcl.ActnList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    procedure Action1Update(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Action2Update(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FileToBeTranferred : Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Action1Update(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.Enabled := not FileToBeTranferred;
end;

procedure TForm1.Action2Update(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action2.Enabled := FileToBeTranferred;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Do some calculation
  //Edit1.Text := Output File Name
  FileToBeTranferred := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Edit1.GetTextLen-4);
  //Upload to Server, wait for completion
  FileToBeTranferred := False;
end;

end.
```